# how to generate number pattern in triangular form

Tags: c

I want to print this pattern like right angled triangle

```
0 
909 
89098 
7890987 
678909876 
56789098765 
4567890987654 
345678909876543 
23456789098765432 
1234567890987654321
```

I wrote following code

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<conio.h>

void main()
{   
    clrscr();
    int i,j,x,z,k,f=1;

    for ( i=10;i>=1;i--,f++)
    {

        for(j=1;j<=f;j++,k--)
    {
            k=i;
            if(k!=10)
            {
                printf("%d",k); 
            }

            if(k==10)
            {
                printf("0");
            }

        }
        for(x=1;x<f;x++,z--)
        {
            z=9;

            printf("%d",z);
        }

        printf("%d/n");

    }
    getch();
}
```

what is wrong with this code? when i check manually it seems correct but when compiled gives different pattern

Comment: This is a question for the stackoverflow site.

Comment: @vignesh welcome to programmers. The stackexchange sites have a lot of help about how things work in each site. Check [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get a feeling about which questions are on topic on programmers.

Comment: but when i try to post in stack exchange...it is not allowed because of bad format which i don't know how to correct

Comment: @VigneshVicky because one question cannot be asked on SO doesn't it can be asked here. You should try to check the link I provided. Also, I don't think that the formatting is the problem. "what's wrong with this code" is not specific enough. You should try to narrow down your problem first. If your only goal is to print this specific pattern, why don't you hard code it in your programm? You see that your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: iam preparing for an interview.i came across this in a blog. i trying to solve it

Comment: Name your variables correctly. `int i,j,x,z,k,f=1;` is asking for you to fired, let alone hired !

Comment: (let's close this thread and get on with the freshen one with the text reformatted and corrected by @Hasturkun).